# org.mule.api.config.ConfigurationException: Error creating bean with name '_muleSimpleRegistryBootstrap'

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, mule, mule-component

I recently joined a new project and I noticed several test failures due to the error below. I am new to mule. Please let me know if you can help:

org.mule.api.config.ConfigurationException: Error creating bean with name '_muleSimpleRegistryBootstrap' defined in URL [jar:file:/.../.m2/repository/org/mule/modules/mule-module-spring-config/3.5.3/mule-module-spring-config-3.5.3.jar!/registry-bootstrap-mule-config.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException: Failed to lookup beans of type interface org.mule.api.transformer.Converter from the Spring registry (org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException)

Comment: "I noticed several test failures", you should probably include the test configuration, for example, do you run the test using Maven ? Do you run it on Jenkins or ? It is probably a jar problem so it might be that some of your dependencies are not available in the test scope.

Comment: Hi Seba.wagner, I run my tests using maven. I will check if it is a jar problem. Thanks.